# Select the text below the pointer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

Does anyone know if it's possible to obtain the text that the mouse pointer is *over* in a web page?

Some assumptions can be made:

1. The web page will contain only text, no images. Minimal styling.
2. The content is all from the same domain, no CORs or iFrames involved.
3. JavaScript events can be applied anywhere, to any element, as needed to make this work.
4. Use of 3rd party client side libs is fine. No server side libs.
5. Use of 'modern' browser APIs is fine, but ideally we can support back to IE9 (no earlier needed)

I'm aware of the Selection API, which allows you to return the selected text. But this is almost the opposite of that: A way to track the pointer, and obtain whatever content it passes over, ideally down to a single word basis, and then select it via code.

I can think of ways to achieve this by rendering the text to a canvas, then tracking pointer movement across the canvas, but I was hoping to find a more 'normal' approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `document.elementFromPoint`, you can find the element your mouse is hovering over.  All you need is an event handler that updates a record of your mouse movement.

```
var pointer = {x: 0, y: 0};
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {
    pointer.x = e.clientX;
    pointer.y = e.clientY;
});
function getTextAtPointer() {
    return document.elementFromPoint(pointer.x,pointer.y).textContent;
}
```

The only problem with this is that it won't tell you what word you're hovering over.  The only solution I can think of would be to parse the text content and wrap every word in a `span` tag, then call `document.elementFromPoint` again to get which specific `span`.  Doing this sounds like a heavy load, so hopefully there's an easier way to go about this problem.

---

**EDIT**

I've decided to try the method of replacing every word with `span` tags, and when I tested it, it didn't seem to affect performance in any perceivable way, so feel free to try it yourself.  Here's the updated `getTextAtPointer` function.

```
function getTextAtPointer() {
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(pointer.x,pointer.y);
    for(var i=elem.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        var node = elem.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType==3) {
            var words = node.textContent.split(/\s+/);
            if(words.length>1) {
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                for(var j=0; j<words.length; j++) {
                    if(words[j].length>0) {
                        var span = document.createElement("span");
                        span.textContent = words[j];
                        frag.appendChild(span);
                        if(j!=words.length-1) {
                            frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
                        }
                    }
                }
                elem.replaceChild(frag,node);
            }
        }
    }
    var word = document.elementFromPoint(pointer.x,pointer.y).textContent;
    if(word.search(/\s+/)!=-1) {
        return "";
    }
    return word;
}
```